# How to convert movielens dataset to matrix with userID as row and movieID as column, and ratings as the elements

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm using the movielens dataset and i want to make a user/item matrix where users represent the rows and items the columns. The ratings would be the individual elements.

I want to do this so i can calculate adjusted cosine similarity faster.

For example matrix[5,12] would give us the rating that user 5 gave for item 12.

I'm new to python so please keep it simple.

Example DF:

cols:

```
 userID,movieID,rating

1,67,4

6,12,2  

2,2,5
```

After conversion this is the matrix M i would get:

...67 12 2

1..4..NA.NA

6..NA.2..NA

2..NA.NA.5

For example M[1,64]==4

Comment: Sample data and expected output ?

Comment: added a simple example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `pivot`

```
s=df.pivot(*df.columns)
movieID   2    12   67
userID                
1        NaN  NaN  4.0
2        5.0  NaN  NaN
6        NaN  2.0  NaN
```

Comment: note to others reading, you can use to_numpy() after the pivot and you got the matrix